# Is the ruby on rails webrick server ever used in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

In a situation where the main server (apache) is offline, is it ever acceptable to run the ruby on rails application on the built in webrick server?  Or should I have a local apache running.  I have to have it available local and it would be very rare it ever ran local but if I had to would it be best to go ahead and install apache or have a batch file that fired up the ruby script/server?  everything has to work the same as the regular online apache server.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Webrick is not a production web server.

[Thin](http://github.com/macournoyer/thin/) and [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) would be good choices - Heroku runs thin, and Github runs unicorn.